My background image isn't displaying in my pong game I made
My background image is failing to load in my pong game I created with Java.
This is my GamePanel.java file where I believe the error is coming from.
Broken code
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.net.URL;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    static final int GAME_WIDTH = 800;
    static final int GAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int BALL_DIAMETER = 20;
    static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 10;
    static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100;
    Paddle player1;
    Paddle player2;
    Ball ball;
    Timer timer;
    int player1Score = 0;
    int player2Score = 0;
    boolean playState = true;
    private Image backgroundImage;
    private SoundEffect scoreSound;  // Declaration of the SoundEffect object

    public GamePanel() {
        player1 = new Paddle(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2), PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 1);
        player2 = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH - PADDLE_WIDTH, (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2), PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 2);
        ball = new Ball((GAME_WIDTH / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2), (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2), BALL_DIAMETER, BALL_DIAMETER);
        loadImage();
        scoreSound = new SoundEffect("/sounds/score.wav");  // Initialize the sound effect

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT));
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void loadImage() {
        // Example path that assumes the 'images' folder is directly in the project root directory
        String path = "/images/backgroundImage.png"; // Adjust this path as needed
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
        if (url == null) {
            System.err.println("Failed to load background image: " + path);
            return;
        }
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(url);
        backgroundImage = ii.getImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (backgroundImage != null) {
            g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 800, 600, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this); // Draw the background full-size
        }
        drawScoreboard(g);
        drawCenterLine(g);
        player1.draw(g);
        player2.draw(g);
        ball.draw(g);
    }
    public void scoreUpdate(int player) {
        if (player == 1) {
            player1Score++;  // Correctly increment player1's score
        } else if (player == 2) {
            player2Score++;  // Correctly increment player2's score
        }
        scoreSound.play(); // Play sound on scoring
    }
    

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (playState) {
            player1.move();
            player2.move();
            ball.move();
        }
        checkCollision();
        repaint();
    }

    public void checkCollision() {
        // Ball bounces off top & bottom window edges
        if (ball.y <= 0 || ball.y >= GAME_HEIGHT - ball.height) {
            ball.setYDirection(-ball.yVelocity);
        }

        // Ball bounces off paddles
        if (ball.intersects(player1) || ball.intersects(player2)) {
            ball.setXDirection(-ball.xVelocity);
        }

        // Ball goes out of bounds
        if (ball.x <= 0) {
            scoreUpdate(2);
            playState = false;
            newPaddles();
            newBall();
            ball.stop();
        } else if (ball.x >= GAME_WIDTH - ball.width) {
            scoreUpdate(1);
            playState = false;
            newPaddles();
            newBall();
            ball.stop();
        }
    }

    public void newPaddles() {
        player1.y = (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2);
        player2.y = (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2);
    }

    public void newBall() {
        ball.x = (GAME_WIDTH / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2);
        ball.y = (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2);
    }




    private void drawScoreboard(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 60));
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(player1Score), (GAME_WIDTH / 4), 50);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(player2Score), (GAME_WIDTH / 4) * 3, 50);
    }

    private void drawCenterLine(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{10}, 0);
        g2d.setStroke(dashed);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.drawLine(GAME_WIDTH / 2, 0, GAME_WIDTH / 2, GAME_HEIGHT);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        player1.keyPressed(e);
        player2.keyPressed(e);
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !playState) {
            playState = true;  // Start moving the ball again
            int direction = (player1Score + player2Score) % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
            ball.start(direction);  // Serve the ball towards the last scorer
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        player1.keyReleased(e);
        player2.keyReleased(e);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}


working code
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    static final int GAME_WIDTH = 800;
    static final int GAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int BALL_DIAMETER = 20;
    static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 10;
    static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100;
    Paddle player1;
    Paddle player2;
    Ball ball;
    Timer timer;
    int player1Score = 0;
    int player2Score = 0;
    boolean playState = true;
    private Image backgroundImage;
    private SoundEffect scoreSound;  // Declaration of the SoundEffect object

    public GamePanel() {
        
        player1 = new Paddle(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2), PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 1);
        player2 = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH - PADDLE_WIDTH, (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2), PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 2);
        ball = new Ball((GAME_WIDTH / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2), (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2), BALL_DIAMETER, BALL_DIAMETER);
        loadImage();
        scoreSound = new SoundEffect("/sounds/score.wav");  // Initialize the sound effect

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT));
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void loadImage() {
        String filePath = "images/br.jpg";  // Relative path from the current working directory
        File file = new File(filePath);
        try {
            backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(file);
            if (backgroundImage != null) {
                System.out.println("Image loaded successfully: Width = " + backgroundImage.getWidth(null) + ", Height = " + backgroundImage.getHeight(null));
            } else {
                System.err.println("Failed to load the image.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception while loading the image: " + e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Failed to load image from path: " + filePath);
        }
    }
    
    


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Draw the background image if it's loaded, otherwise draw a black background
        if (backgroundImage != null) {
            g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        }
        drawScoreboard(g);
        drawCenterLine(g);
        player1.draw(g);
        player2.draw(g);
        ball.draw(g);
    }
    
    public void scoreUpdate(int player) {
        if (player == 1) {
            player1Score++;  // Correctly increment player1's score
        } else if (player == 2) {
            player2Score++;  // Correctly increment player2's score
        }
        scoreSound.play(); // Play sound on scoring
    }
    

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (playState) {
            player1.move();
            player2.move();
            ball.move();
        }
        checkCollision();
        repaint();
    }

    public void checkCollision() {
        // Ball bounces off top & bottom window edges
        if (ball.y <= 0 || ball.y >= GAME_HEIGHT - ball.height) {
            ball.setYDirection(-ball.yVelocity);
        }

        // Ball bounces off paddles
        if (ball.intersects(player1) || ball.intersects(player2)) {
            ball.setXDirection(-ball.xVelocity);
        }

        // Ball goes out of bounds
        if (ball.x <= 0) {
            scoreUpdate(2);
            playState = false;
            newPaddles();
            newBall();
            ball.stop();
        } else if (ball.x >= GAME_WIDTH - ball.width) {
            scoreUpdate(1);
            playState = false;
            newPaddles();
            newBall();
            ball.stop();
        }
    }

    public void newPaddles() {
        player1.y = (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2);
        player2.y = (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2);
    }

    public void newBall() {
        ball.x = (GAME_WIDTH / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2);
        ball.y = (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2);
    }




    private void drawScoreboard(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 60));
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(player1Score), (GAME_WIDTH / 4), 50);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(player2Score), (GAME_WIDTH / 4) * 3, 50);
    }

    private void drawCenterLine(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{10}, 0);
        g2d.setStroke(dashed);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.drawLine(GAME_WIDTH / 2, 0, GAME_WIDTH / 2, GAME_HEIGHT);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        player1.keyPressed(e);
        player2.keyPressed(e);
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !playState) {
            playState = true;  // Start moving the ball again
            int direction = (player1Score + player2Score) % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
            ball.start(direction);  // Serve the ball towards the last scorer
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        player1.keyReleased(e);
        player2.keyReleased(e);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}

My file format:

I tried renaming files and changing the naming conventions to make sure everything was the same.
I have tried different png files to see if there was some issue with the png file i was using.
I have even consulted AI with this problem and haven't come up with any better results.
What the game looks like and what it should look like with the proper background image.
https://imgur.com/a/sER5OM1

EDIT: The problem has been resolved here is the working code, I will leave it here as a reference in case anyone else encounters a similar problem.

Look at the source code for this constructor of class javax.swing.ImageIcon. If the constructor fails to load the image then it doesn't throw an exception, it simply creates an ImageIcon instance without an image. I suggest that you call method getImage, after creating the ImageIcon to verify that the image was successfully loaded.

This seems wrong.  The x, y coordinates here are going to be pretty far away from the center or the edge of the frame:
g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 800, 600, this.getWidth(),
    this.getHeight(), this);

Trying drawing at 0,0 rather that 800,600 just to see if that fixes the problem.
EDIT: this worked when I tried it.  There might be a problem you aren't showing us.  Full code:
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package overflow21;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Brenden
 */
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    static final int GAME_WIDTH = 800;
    static final int GAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    static final int BALL_DIAMETER = 20;
    static final int PADDLE_WIDTH = 10;
    static final int PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100;
//    Paddle player1;
//    Paddle player2;
//    Ball ball;
    Timer timer;
    int player1Score = 0;
    int player2Score = 0;
    boolean playState = true;
    private Image backgroundImage;
//    private SoundEffect scoreSound;  // Declaration of the SoundEffect object
    
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater( GamePanel::start );
   }
    
    private static void start() {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Game Panel");
       
       GamePanel game = new GamePanel();
       frame.add( game );
       
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
       frame.pack();
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
       frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public GamePanel() {
//        player1 = new Paddle(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2), PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 1);
//        player2 = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH - PADDLE_WIDTH, (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2), PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 2);
//        ball = new Ball((GAME_WIDTH / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2), (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2), BALL_DIAMETER, BALL_DIAMETER);
        loadImage();
//        scoreSound = new SoundEffect("/sounds/score.wav");  // Initialize the sound effect

        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT));
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    private void loadImage() {
        // Example path that assumes the 'images' folder is directly in the project root directory
        System.err.println( "Loading..." );
        String path = "overflow21/images/mountains.jpg"; // Adjust this path as needed
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
        if (url == null) {
            System.err.println("Failed to load background image: " + path);
            return;
        }
        
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(url);
        System.err.println( ii );
        backgroundImage = ii.getImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (backgroundImage != null) {
            g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null ); // Draw the background full-size
        }
        drawScoreboard(g);
        drawCenterLine(g);
//        player1.draw(g);
//        player2.draw(g);
//        ball.draw(g);
    }
    public void scoreUpdate(int player) {
        if (player == 1) {
            player1Score++;  // Correctly increment player1's score
        } else if (player == 2) {
            player2Score++;  // Correctly increment player2's score
        }
//        scoreSound.play(); // Play sound on scoring
    }
    

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (playState) {
//            player1.move();
//            player2.move();
//            ball.move();
        }
        checkCollision();
        repaint();
    }

    public void checkCollision() {
//        // Ball bounces off top & bottom window edges
//        if (ball.y <= 0 || ball.y >= GAME_HEIGHT - ball.height) {
//            ball.setYDirection(-ball.yVelocity);
//        }
//
//        // Ball bounces off paddles
//        if (ball.intersects(player1) || ball.intersects(player2)) {
//            ball.setXDirection(-ball.xVelocity);
//        }
//
//        // Ball goes out of bounds
//        if (ball.x <= 0) {
//            scoreUpdate(2);
//            playState = false;
//            newPaddles();
//            newBall();
//            ball.stop();
//        } else if (ball.x >= GAME_WIDTH - ball.width) {
//            scoreUpdate(1);
//            playState = false;
//            newPaddles();
//            newBall();
//            ball.stop();
//        }
    }

    public void newPaddles() {
//        player1.y = (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2);
//        player2.y = (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (PADDLE_HEIGHT / 2);
    }

    public void newBall() {
//        ball.x = (GAME_WIDTH / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2);
//        ball.y = (GAME_HEIGHT / 2) - (BALL_DIAMETER / 2);
    }




    private void drawScoreboard(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 60));
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(player1Score), (GAME_WIDTH / 4), 50);
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(player2Score), (GAME_WIDTH / 4) * 3, 50);
    }

    private void drawCenterLine(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Stroke dashed = new BasicStroke(3, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0, new float[]{10}, 0);
        g2d.setStroke(dashed);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.drawLine(GAME_WIDTH / 2, 0, GAME_WIDTH / 2, GAME_HEIGHT);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
//        player1.keyPressed(e);
//        player2.keyPressed(e);
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !playState) {
            playState = true;  // Start moving the ball again
            int direction = (player1Score + player2Score) % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
//            ball.start(direction);  // Serve the ball towards the last scorer
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
//        player1.keyReleased(e);
//        player2.keyReleased(e);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}

Output:


I just tried this and unfortunately, there was no change to the background image in the game. It still isn't displaying the PNG image

See my update, it worked when I tried it.

Thanks for the help, turned out my PNG file was corrupted because of all the problems it could have been. I resolved the issue by making the original changes you suggested then I threw the PNG image file into MS Paint changed it to a JPEG saved it correcting the background image loading error.

i think the main problem is this right here
 g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 800, 600, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this); // Draw the background full-size
your drawing your image at 800, 600 which is near the bottom right of the window.
\if your doing full size you need to put the x y at 0,0 so it start in the top left corner of the screen.
you also shouldnt need to specify a width or a height since it is a image. if you replace that line it should work. replace it with this:
 g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this)
or just
g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this)
if that didnt work you can try a few methods i think might be good for you.
it might be good to change the kind of image you are using try using a buffered image or a Image stream, heres one you can try to use
bgImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath)) //encase in try catch with an IOException 
i think you should try setting the observer of the bg image when drawing to null it might help.
i also think you should try to combine your code instead of a bunch of methods, modularity is good and clean but it can produce alot of confusion with scope and the like so you should draw all your things in a paint method together. i also dont see how your looping over
